# Where I can buy good resources to build games?

Tags: game-development

Where I can buy boards, cards, dice, fake money, figures, and any sort of pieces? It would be nice if the store sells on the internet.

Another good reason is to buy replacements for damaged or lost pieces.

Comment: You might want to accept an answer for this question, if there's an answer that meets your needs. If not, I'd recommend asking for clarification in comments, or editing your question to be more specific, so people can edit their answers or write new ones that will better answer your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping recommendations and it is attracting spam.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a list from BoardGameGeek:

[Industry Sources](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/66420/attention-industry-sources)

It should get you started on the path to finding everything you need.

Answer (score 13):

Just go to [The Game Crafter](http://www.thegamecrafter.com/)

Comment: What makes this a good site to visit? Without at least a basic description, it's hard to separate this from the other answers.

Answer (score 9):

Some game stores do sell a number of game creation items.  I would check with your friendly local game store and see if they carry the Fantasy Flight Game Supply line which currently includes card sleeves, game tokens, and plastic stands.  Dice should be relatively easy to come by at your game store as well, and I know Chessex carries a full line of white or creme blank dice in 4,6,8,10,12 or 20 sided varieties.

My local gamestore also carries pawns and blank playing cards, but I know that isn't necessarily the norm.  For any items you can't find locally, the internet is always worth a search.

Comment: Teacher supply stores frequently carry blank pieces and other resources, too.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for one-off pieces, for play testing purposes and such (rather than having custom pieces made for final production of something), I'd hit up yard sales and thrift stores.

I typically wouldn't recommend them, as you can't be sure most games are complete, but in this case, getting a bunch of partial games cheaply might be an advantage.

Comment: bargain hunting, I like it!  I've picked up a lot of complete boardgames over the years for $1 at garage sales.  Probably 75% of what I've bought ends up being complete.

Comment: I know which of my local thrift stores count pieces before taping game boxes shut. The others, I either open them and count myself, or just assume pieces are missing when making the purchasing decision.
Either way, you can get money, dice, counters, minuteglasses, spinners, tokens, and all sorts of other stuff for pennies on the dollar.

Answer (score 3):

Dice will probably be the least of your problems since you can buy them at any game store. As for other elements I'd look on eBay. You could probably buy some cheap board games and combine them to make your dream game.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to go straight to the manufacturer, Tom Jolly has another current and good list of sources at http://beach.silcom.com/~tomjolly/design2.htm

Answer (score 1):

At board game expositions like [Spiel Essen](http://www.merz-verlag.com/), they sell game pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://www.SpielMaterial.de in Germany and Plastics for Games (http://www.p4g.co.uk/) in the UK before and been happy with both. Plastics for Games are definitely a buy in bulk sort of place though, from what I remember.