# What is the best resource for Card Trays?

Tags: playing-cards, components, custom-game-pieces

I'm looking for some card trays for a game I've been designing.

Ideally, they would be six-slot trays that hold standard playing card sized cards.
In my mind, they are similar in appearance and quality to the trays that are used to hold money in monopoly.  I've found some things that are similar, but nothing exactly like that.
I'd need one for each player.

Any recommended resources for something like that?
My best solution right now is pillaging thrift store games.

This could be expanded into a broader question - 
what are the best websites and box stores for buying game-making materials?

Something like this tray is what I'm looking for:
[image: Monopoly money tray]

Comment: For game-making materials, see also [Where I can buy good resources to build games?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/131/6)

Answer (score 1):

Without parameters on shape, size, and cost, it's difficult to give a good answer.  However, if it were my game and I needed 4-5 6-slot horizontal card slots, I would consider making them out of folded cardboard.  With a little trial and error it should be simple to shape what you need from 7x3 (21) horizontal folds, and 3 vertical folds with 2-4 tabs to keep the shape.

If you want plastic, you likely want to purchase your own vacuum former.  Hobby versions can be had for as little as $120 (plus materials).  They work by laying a piece of plastic over a mold you create to form any plastic shape you want.

[Random site selling a former](http://www.widgetworksunlimited.com/Vacuum_Formers_s/35.htm)

Comment: The size & shape parameters are standard playing card size, 2.5 x 3.5 inches, times six slots, in parallel.  I don't have any specific cost expectations - I just want to know if there's anywhere that sells these or would make them.  Interesting idea with the vacuum former.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something similar to the card trays from [Rack-O](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/917/rack-o)? I believe Rack-O sets come with four of these and are pretty cheap.

[image]

Comment: More akin to a monopoly money tray http://scavenging.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/monopoly_money_hi.jpg, but with wider slots.  Cool suggestion though, i could see these being useful.

Comment: Ah, I see. Go ahead and add that picture to your question. Maybe the visual will trigger someone's memory. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough rep yet to post the image.

Comment: I added the image tag as an edit. If it is approved it will appear.

Comment: Approved it for ya.