# Where can I find wooden pieces (or alternates) for Diplomacy?

Tags: diplomacy, components

I'd like to play Diplomacy, and have the old Avalon Hill version of the game which, unfortunately, comes with plastic pieces (stars and anchors). It also lacks indicators of who controls which supply centers.

I like the original wooden pieces, seen here:

[image]

Fleets are clearly fleets, armies are clearly armies, and supply centers are demarcated by the colored circles.

Another good example are these pieces:

[image]

What works as a viable replacement for these parts? Where can I find them? I've seen around suggestions to:

1. Make them myself - this is time-consuming, and (for me) generally doesn't work out well
2. Use wooden beads - while this works, it doesn't really look professional
3. Purchase parts sets - these are typically expensive; I haven't found anything that wouldn't require a large investment to complete
4. Use the original wooden Risk parts - these lack enough fleets required to run a game, as well as lack supply center indicators. They're also expensive

I'm looking for better options. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have any skill 3d rendering or know someone who does, you can make the models on Shapeways and have them printed in metal stone or plastic.

Comment: @Pow I have checked that, and unfortunately, it comes out to about $220 if I'd like to print in sandstone, second cheapest option.

Comment: Many companies sell miscellaneous tokens, [Fantasy Flight](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=86&esem=2&esum=182) for one.

Comment: I could produce cubes, rectangles and circles with my laser cutter (or even more complicated 2d shapes such as the image at the bottom of [this](http://www.makeacanoe.com/OB15d1.gif)), but I don't have 7 colours of paint.

Comment: In the UK, a shop called Wilkinson stocks its own very cheap Lego-compatible bricks that are very similar in dimensions to the wooden cubes. You can select your own and there are enough colours to make a full Diplomacy set. (Army: 2x2 brick, Fleet: 1x4 flat brick with an optional 2x1 on the top to make a sail.)

Answer (score 2):

Please, check the following question: [What's a good source of generic pieces/components?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/whats-a-good-source-of-generic-pieces-components) There are a lot of board game components shops listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a board game bits store like http://www.meeplesource.com/ ?